# How to correctly install Zend Framework 3 with Composer?

Tags: zend-framework3

I'm trying to install Zend Framework 3, but I don't know why I get ZF 2.51.
I've followed the Zend docs https://framework.zend.com/downloads
and after I've launched the command to create the project if I go to the home of the project just created, I see "Welcome to Zend Framework 2"
Congratulations! You have successfully installed the ZF2 Skeleton Application. You are currently running Zend Framework version 2.5.1. This skeleton can serve as a simple starting point for you to begin building your application on ZF2.

What I have wrong?

composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install

I've update Composer to the latest version 1.8.3, but I still can't use Zend 3.
When I try to use:
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application projectname "3.0" I get this error:
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package zendframework/skeleton-application with version ^3.0
  .

Comment: In version 3, Zend\Version class in no longuer used. You can find if you are in version 3 by looking in composer.lock the version number of Zend\Mvc. It must be greter than 3.0

Comment: [Given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450810/1155833) should work. However, instead you could download the [Skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), which gives you a basic working setup out of the box instead of just the vendor requirements (after you unzip/mount somewhere and run a `composer install`)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a version number:

`composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application /path/to/install ^3.0`

Worked for me. Looks like it automatically pulls an older version.

Comment: I get this error   [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find package zendframework/skeleton-application with version ^3.0  
  .

Comment: What about `composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application ./zend 3.0.3`? Also what platform are you on?

Comment: Both of the commands above run fine for me on OS 10.13.4... try wrapping the version number with single quotes? That command should really not be giving you any grief. Positive the error isn't saying the directory is already occupied?

Comment: I've tried this:
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application testzend3 "3.0" but I get the same error, but when I try this I successfully create a project:
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application testzend3 "2.5"
Could be a composer problem or a skeleton-application problem?